# Editing systemd config files - when do changes become effective?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, systemd

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I've just edited `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` to disable "suspend" mode. The UI's "Settings" picked up the change after a short while, by no longer displaying suspend-related options.

Does that mean that systemd has also quickly noticed the change automatically, or is there something I have to do to make the changes effective? (I've checked the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html), and nothing is mentioned about it).

If it's automatic, is there somewhere that logs it? I've checked `/var/log/syslog` and `journalctl -u systemd-suspend.service` and there's nothing obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if a service has a configuration file you can use `systemctl reload <service>`. If it was a unit file itself that you edited then you can use `systemctl daemon-reload` or just restart the particular service.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it: `Failed to reload systemd-suspend.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit systemd-suspend.service.` - would that be expected here, please?

Comment: Yes, some services don't action the "reload" command. Did you try the `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: Yep ... not sure if that stimulated a reload or if it happened anyway (I was debugging a suspend issue, and it was hard to do if I didn't know if my changes were being picked up!). Anyway, suspend has stopped happening, so all good. Thanks again :-)